# Update Oracle database and SQL Server 2008 R2 database within a transaction

Tags: c#, ado.net, transactions, distributed-transactions

I need to perform update in a table in Oracle as well as update a table in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Is it possible to run them in a transaction using ADO.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as an eXtended Architecture (XA) transaction, and yes, it is supported on Microsoft Windows via the MSDTC.exe application.

You can read all about it here:  [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753563(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753563%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)  another good article describing how to configure the DTC to support transaction with Oracle is here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa344212(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa344212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)